# ApprovalTests with TestCase (Nunit) use the same approval file

Tags: c#, nunit, approval-tests

I have a problem that using ApprovalTests.Net and NUnit all the tests that are run use the same approval file which name originates from Test method name.

Is it possible to specify somehow for each test case separate approval file?

```
[Test]
[TestCase("test",TestName="Test1")]
[TestCase("test2",TestName="Test2")]
Testing_Method(string param)
{
   //somestuff
   ObjectApprover.VerifyJson(someObject); // fails for second case 
                                          // because it uses the same 
                                          // approval file as the first case,
                                          // which is not the same
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net/issues/93

Comment: saw it but though someone might know a workaround for that or a good alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
ApprovalResults.ForScenario("extra info")
```

Like such:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("test",TestName="Test1")]
[TestCase("test2",TestName="Test2")]
Testing_Method(string param)
{
   //somestuff
   using (ApprovalTests.Namers.ApprovalResults.ForScenario(param))
   {
       ObjectApprover.VerifyJson(someObject); 
   }
}
```

This will result in 2 approval files:

```
TestClassName.Testing_Method.ForScenario.Test1.approved.json
TestClassName.Testing_Method.ForScenario.Test2.approved.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [TestCase] attribute, you could use [TestCaseSource] attribute.

https://ignas.me/tech/nunit-testcasesource-example/ - TestCaseSource example with explanation.

Comment: I dont think it solves the problem with ObjectApprover